# How to retrieve user's newsfeed list (VK.com)?

Tags: php, mysql, feed

I am using following php code :

```
$vk = new VK($app_id, $api_secret);

$user_wall = $vk->api('newsfeed.get', array(
                         //'owner_id' => $o->profile_uid,
                         'count' => 100,
                         'filters' => 'post,photo,wall_photo,friend',
                         'access_token' => $o->profile_token
                     ));

echo '<pre>';
print_r($user_wall);
exit;
```

I am getting error when trying above code. I have successfully completed auth and stored user profile info in mysql table. I notice that when I see Api.Console permission in App> Setting, I see Access the Wall permission. But in application I used to retrieve data, I do not see this permission.

> Error description : Permission to perform this action is denied
>
> Error code : 7

The documentation is poorly described. Even which field is required or optional I can not determine. And what is difference between wall.get with filter "others" vs newsfeed.get ?

LOGIN CODE:

```
$AuthURL = $vk->getAuthorizeURL('notify,friends,photos,audio,video,docs,notes,pages,status,offers,questions,wall,groups,notifications,stats,ads,offline', $redirect_uri);
```

AUTH CODE:

```
$vk_code = $_REQUEST['code'];

$vk = new VK($app_id, $app_secret);

$access_token = $vk->getAccessToken($vk_code, $redirect_uri);

$uid = $access_token['user_id'];

$token = $access_token['access_token'];

$user_info = $vk->api('users.get', array(
        'user_ids'       => $uid,
        'fields'        => 'nickname, screen_name, sex, bdate (birthdate), city, country, timezone, photo, photo_medium, photo_big, has_mobile, contacts, education, online, counters, relation, last_seen, activity, can_write_private_message, can_see_all_posts, can_post, universities, counters'       
));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First you must register application: *vk.com/editapp?act=create*
2. Then you need **get authorize code**. To do this follow link:
   oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=**{APP_ID}**&scope=**{API_SETTINGS}**
   Where **{APP_ID}** — your application id (see on app settings page),
   **{API_SETTINGS}** — access rights requested by your app (through comma). If need infinite token use key "offline". For newsfeed need use key "**wall,friends,offline**".
   Opens page. Copy string in URL **AFTER** #code=
3. Later you need **get access token**. Go to link:
   https://oauth.vk.com/access_token?client_id=**{APP_ID}**&client_secret=**{API_SECRET}**&code=**{CODE}**
   Where **{API_SECRET}** — secret application key (see on app settings page),
   **{CODE}** — code that was copied in step 2.
   **Copy access_token**.
4. To get newsfeed data request link:
   https://api.vk.com/method/newsfeed.get.xml?access_token=**{ACCESS_TOKEN}**
   Where **{ACCESS_TOKEN}** — token that was in step 3.

NOTE: USE HTTPS WHEN USING THIS ACTIONS

Comment: I already registered application and replace id & secret in my code
Even i am able to fetch user profile data.
The only problem is when try to fetch news i am getting error.
IN your 4th step i am passing token also.
If you have working php code, please post.

Comment: See my question now, i have edited and put login and auth callback code now.. app_id & secret key is my application key & secret.

Answer (score 0):

You need the following rights to call this method: wall and friends. ([Read more on rights](http://vk.com/dev/permissions))

You must generate authorization with wall and friends...

https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=APP_ID&scope=wall,friends,offline

Just replace APP_ID with your appilication and then get your token

Comment: Hi Ayxan, I used following scope :

notify,friends,photos,audio,video,docs,notes,pages,status,offers,questions,wall,groups,notifications,stats,ads,offline

I think i used almost all scope, to avoid permission issue.

Any idea still i am getting error.