# Getting error 15 "Access denied: no access to call this method" when calling vKontakte API method newsfeed.get

Tags: vk

I'm trying to get users newsfeed posts from vk.com using their API. However, the only response I get when calling any of the newsfeed.{method} methods is error code `15` with the error message `Access denied: no access to call this method`. I'm working in PH using the [vkPhpSdk](https://github.com/AndriiHeonia/vkPhpSdk) class.

I've consulted Google, but the only post in english I could find that seems relevant is [How to retrieve user's newsfeed list (VK.com)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18802173/how-to-retrieve-users-newsfeed-list-vk-com) and I've made sure that all the steps in that correct answer is fulfilled, still no change. There are a lot of results in russian, but since I don't speak (read) russian and Google Translate aren't that great, I'm stuck...

When i check up the error code (`15`, https://vk.com/dev/errors) it only says:

> **15 Access denied**
>   Make sure that you use correct identifiers and the content is available for the user in the full version of the site.

I did however find this https://toster.ru/q/110871 which seems do be saying that VK website applications (which is the one I have) gets ignored by the newsfeed methods. Is this true?

Any help, tips or suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use **wall.get**

Method: https://vk.com/dev/wall.get

Its open method, you can use it without any authorization.

Example for group: http://api.vkontakte.ru/method/wall.get?owner_id=-1611

Example for user: http://api.vkontakte.ru/method/wall.get?owner_id=1